# On-air light circuit interface

Tags: circuit-protection, interface

I need help for the design of on-air light interface. The DB15 connector output of console arc10 is 12 V, 200 mA (max). The load is on-air light bulb, 230 V AC. I'm considering the interface circuit between arc10 console output and the load to be the optocoupler with a triac.

Is it ok to just use a resistor voltage divider to convert the DB15 connector output 12 V DC 200 mA to a 5 V DC optocoupler input without any issue? What about the drawn current of the optocoupler input? What value of resistor to satisfy the optocoupler input drawn current.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a divider, you can just increase the value of the current limiting resistor in series with the optocoupler's LED. The resistance you need follows ohm's law: \$R=\frac V I\$. To compute \$V\$, subtract the forward voltage of the LED (taken from the datasheet) from your supply voltage. The value of \$I\$ (the optocoupler LED current) is also taken from the datasheet.

Alternatively, you can skip building your own triac-based switch and just buy a solid state relay (SSR) module. You can buy them with 12V inputs, which will allow you to connect it directly to your console without any extra electronics.